# 'bundle install' not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I created a new rails project by `rails new app` . Then the command prompt showed the creation of a few files and then is displayed `run bundle install` and showed some stuff after that.

However, then I changed the Gemfile to add some new gems and ran `bundle install` again to install those gems but I get `invalid argument` error. So, how do I run bundle install?

Rails version : 3.2.1,
Ruby version  : 1.9.3

Here's the Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0.beta.18'
end

group :test do
    gem 'rspec', '2.0.0.beta.18'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

**Update**

As is turns out I had installed something called MoSync some time back and it probably came with a bundle command with it. So, when I was typing `bundle install`, it was trying to run something else but couldn't find a valid argument.

It became clear when I typed just `bundle` in the powershell and saw this:

```
MAUtil::MAFS Bundle tool

This tool is used to build a binary image of a folder on a desktop computer.

Usage:
bundle <parameters>

Parameters:
  -in <input file or folder> the input files or folders to add to the
                             image (multiple -in directives may be added).
  -out <output file>         the name of the image to be created (only one).
  -toUpper/-toLower          change case of all file names to upper or lower
                             case.

Example:
  bundle -in data -out anotherworld.bun -toLower
```

Comment: Show us your Gemfile, most likely there's an error in it. Also show us the actual error output. You're not giving us enough information to help you, and we can't guess :)

Comment: @Agis the error is just that much only. Two words, that is.

Comment: There is a typo in `rspec-rails`  vresion string: 'bete' instead of 'beta'. I'm not sure if it is the problem, but you can try :).

Comment: @Jatin No line errors? Strange.. Try a `bundle show`. How did you install Bundler? Also there's an error in your rspec gem (`bete` should be `beta`).

Comment: @Agis I used rails installer(railsinstaller.org). It installed the bundler for me. And the error appears even after removing the typo.

Comment: @Jatin Have you tried `bundle show`? What does it output?

Comment: @Agis bundle show gives the same error `invalid argument`

Comment: You say that you add some new gems, what gems did you add? Did you try to remove them and launche bundle install again? Did it raise the same error? If not you can add your gems one by one and find the one that's raising the error.

Comment: @Kulgar When I say I added new gems, I meant that I added their names in the Gemfile. Then I ran `bundle install`. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: @Kulgar Also, even if I run bundle install without changing the Gemfile, it still gives the same error.

Comment: @Jatin: so, we can assume that the bug doesn't come from your Gemfile. What's your OS? Windows? If so, I would have rather use: http://rubyinstaller.org/ taking the last version of ruby and DevKit, then installing bundler as a gem then Rails as a gem. :) RailsInstaller doesn't have an up to date Ruby version, and bundler is version 1.2 nowadays... Not sure if it will solve anything but you can try and it may be a problem of compatibility between ruby and gems.

Comment: @Kulgar I am on windows. Well, I might give it a go if I run into more problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't go far if you can't solve this bundle bug :-( ... Gems are the heart of Rails... Maybe I should try to install rails installer and see if I have the same problem? ^^'

Comment: Ok, I've installed ruby and rails using the railsinstaller... I created a new project, change my Gemfile with yours and did a bundle install and it worked perfectly... So, your bug definitely comes from your environment and I can't see a way to reproduce your bug... :-( You could try to post an issue on the railsinstaller google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/railsinstaller They should have more experienced than any stackoverflow reader about their own tool and environment compatibilities issues... Don't forget to edit your question if they help you to fix your bug.

Comment: @Kulgar Thanks! Appreciate you help! Will update if I get a solution.

Comment: @Kulgar Apparently, the problem was something entirely different as I have updated the question details.

Comment: That's great! It'll surely help others if they have the same error with bundle command. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MAUtil::MAFS Bundle tool

This tool is used to build a binary image of a folder on a desktop computer.

Usage:
bundle <parameters>

Parameters:
  -in <input file or folder> the input files or folders to add to the
                             image (multiple -in directives may be added).
  -out <output file>         the name of the image to be created (only one).
  -toUpper/-toLower          change case of all file names to upper or lower
                             case.

Example:
  bundle -in data -out anotherworld.bun -toLower
```

That bundle command executed from Mosync.
Check this link.
http://www.mosync.com/docs/sdk/cpp/guides/storage/mafs-library/index.html

[SOLUTION 1]
Remove Mosync from SYSTEM PATH then try to use bundle again.

[SOLUTION 2]
Direct access for bundle for ruby

```
C:\Ruby193\bin\bundle install
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to either create an alias using `doskey`:

```
doskey bundull=C:\ruby\bin\bundle
bundull install
```

Or run it with the full path:

```
C:\ruby\bin\bundle install
```

**Note that C:\ruby\ should be changed to the path you installed Rails Installer to.**

You can also adjust your path and make `C:\ruby\` the most important by going to "*Control Panel > System > Environment Variables* (button at the bottom)" and then editing Path and moving the path to Rails Installer up higher (before anything else.)  Doing this method will prevent errors with Rails in the future but occasionally you will have to adjust your path because other things can adjust your path while installing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are running Windows OS.  Perhaps it might be a hidden character somewhere?  The easiest thing to do is to install something like RVM (Ruby Version Manager).  I believe it is Pik for Windows (https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/).  Try installing again.

Also try removing everything after 'beta' in

> 2.0.0.beta.18

to make it

> gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0.beta'